# Django Send Mail function not working on patch request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my viewset I have a method that as far as I can tell should be sending an email when I make a patch request but for some reason the email is not sending.

Method:

```
def patch(self, request, video_id):
        video = Video.objects.get(pk=request.data['video_id'])
        serializer = VideoSerializer(
            data=request.data, instance=video, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            send_mail('Subject',
                      'Message',
                      'from@email.com',
                      ['to@gmail.com',],
                      fail_silently=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is the complete viewset:

```
class AllCompletedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = VideoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Video.objects.all().filter(Q(completed=True))
        return queryset

    def patch(self, request, video_id):
            video = Video.objects.get(pk=request.data['video_id'])
            serializer = VideoSerializer(
                data=request.data, instance=video, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                send_mail('Subject',
                          'Message',
                          'from@email.com',
                          ['to@gmail.com',],
                          fail_silently=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here are the email settings in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'thehost'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'thehostusername'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'thepassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you provide your email settings in settings.py ?

Comment: seems like the execution is not going inside the if clause, (`if serializer.is_valid()`...)

Comment: maybe serializer is not valid, try to print `serializer.errors`.

Comment: Linh Nguyen, I added the email settings.  I doubt they are the issue though.

Comment: I'm not getting any serializer errors back and the data in the database is updating correctly so it seems that the serializer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

check with serializer exceptions

```
class AllCompletedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = VideoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Video.objects.all().filter(Q(completed=True))
        return queryset

    def patch(self, request, video_id):
            video = Video.objects.get(pk=request.data['video_id'])
            serializer = VideoSerializer(
                data=request.data, instance=video, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
                send_mail('Subject',
                          'Message',
                          'from@email.com',
                          ['to@gmail.com',],
                          fail_silently=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors and the data in the database is updated correctly.  It just doesn't want to send the email.

Comment: which email service you are using

Comment: i've tested with both my gmail and my hosting (mochahost)

Comment: I wrote a send mail method in the serializer instead of the viewset and that works. I still have no clue why this method didnt work.